# How to check for three or more whitespaces in string - Python

Tags: python, string, encryption

I need a method to check if there are three o whitespaces a string. Currently I only know how to check **if there is** a whitespace, with this: `if " " in someString:`. The reason why I want to find how many whitespaces there are, is because I need to narrow the search down of decrypted messages.

You see, the encrypted message is a long string of random letters and numbers. I use `itertools.product("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå", repeat=6)` to generate a set of keys, assuming the length of the key is six. In order to find the correct original message, which is a **setence in english** I need to narrow down the search. I figured out that checking for three or more whitespaces in a string is a great way to do so, since a sentence usually consist of multiple whitespaces.

I really want some tips, rather than the solution, since this is a task I want to figure out by myself! :D

Comment: Here's a tip, read what whitespace actually is.

Comment: try `someString.count(' ')` if you are interested only in <kbd>space</kbd> characters

Comment: Thanks guys! Should I remove the post?

Comment: @AndreasAmundsen In your post, replace all instances of the word 'whitespace' with 'space'

Comment: "Whitespace" is a generic term and includes tabs ("\t"), new-lines ("\n") and carriage-returns ("\r") - the phrase does not just mean a space character.

Comment: Considering your original question, you might consider using regular expressions with the `\b` anchor.  This marks word-boundaries, which could include any white-space character, punctuation, and start/end of line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually interested in the exact count of any character that is considered white space, you could use something like this:

```
s = " nar\trow down the se\narch."
num_whitespace = len([c for c in s if c in [' ', '\n', '\t']])
print(num_whitespace) # 6
```

Of course, you can add some whitespace characters as needed.